# Foam Overflow - Residue on Carboy walls

Tags: fermentation, foam, blow-off, sediment, beginner

I recently brewed up a Caribou Slobber from Northern Brewing. I had a foam over, I sanitized a new stopper, air lock and resealed the carboy. Now I have no bubbles in my airlock, and all of the sediment is on the walls of the carboy and not on top of the wort (so it is not touching the wort and therefore will not fall to the bottom). Is my brew okay? Its been over a week of this, should I transfer to secondary carboy for secondary fermentation?

thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a vigorous, but otherwise normal fermentation. Rack to secondary, if that's your process, or leave it in the carboy for another week or two before bottling. The krausen residue on the walls of the carboy won't affect the final beer.

In the future you might consider using a blow-off tube instead of an airlock.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Will use a blow-off tube in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're fine.  No, don't xfer to a secondary...at least not yet.  You probably don't need a secondary at all.  A lot of brewers have found that it's unnecessary.  If you decide you want to xfer, give it at least 3 weeks in primary first.  There's nothing wrong with leaving it in there that long.

Comment: thanks for the help! Glad to know my beer is still in good shape!